# Is there a postActionEvent for a JComboBox?

Tags: java, macos, swing, jcombobox, key-events

I successfully use *postActionEvent()* on a JTextField that has an ActionListener to simulate User action (pressing Enter key).  I would like to create the same type of simulation for a JComboBox that has an ActionListener, but I don't find a *postActionEvent()* for a JComboBox.  How could this (simulating User pressing Enter key) be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

> How could this (simulating User pressing Enter key) be accomplished?

Combobox has an `"enterPressed"` Action. So you should be able to access the `Action` from the `ActionMap` of the combobox and then manually invoke the `actionPerformed(...)` method of the Action.

Check out [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a program to list all the bindings for all Swing components.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding Key Bindings.  I'll continue studying.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a KeyListener:

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            if (((JTextComponent) ((JComboBox) ((Component) event
                    .getSource()).getParent()).getEditor()
                    .getEditorComponent()).getText().isEmpty())
                System.out.println("please dont make me blank");
        }
    }
});
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056301/java-editable-jcombobox-keylistener-event-for-enter-key)

Comment: This doesn't "simulate" the user invoking the Enter key. Also, Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`, not a KeyListener.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. After reading the other question a little bit more, I see that.