# What is the difference between adding a KeyListener to JCombobox editor and JCombobox itself

Tags: java, swing

```
    listItemsCombo.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new keyPressListener()); //Works correct
```

This works fine. But , On adding keyListener to the jcomboBox , keyPress is not getting recoganized while pressing "Enter". What is the exact difference between adding a keyListener to the jComboxBox and adding a listener to its editor?When to add Listeners to editor?

```
   listItemsCombo.addKeyListener(new KeyPressListener())//When should we use this?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Editable JCombobox Keylistener event for Enter key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056301/java-editable-jcombobox-keylistener-event-for-enter-key)

Comment: It works well when I use editor's listener.But my question is when to use it?Y we use it?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the exact difference between adding a keyListener to the jComboxBox and adding a listener to its editor?

KeyEvents are only dispatched to the component that has focus.

> When to add Listeners to editor?

You should not use a KeyListener on the combo box or the editor. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`. With Key Bindings you can handle a `KeyStroke` even if the components doesn't have focus (if you wish). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

Comment: KeyBindings can be used.  I need to Listen to the KeyTyped too. KeyBindings can be used for KeyPress. But for getting userInput from the keyBoard (keys like abc ..), I need to add a keyListener right?Or it can be performed with keyBindings?

Comment: @divya, Key Bindings is used when you want to invoke an Action when a specific key is pressed. If you just want to know when text is added to the text field then you should use a `DocumentListener`. The tutorial also has a section on "How to Write a DocumentListener".